# AndEngine Loading Graphics: Where Do I put my assets folder and my resources?

Tags: java, android, oop, bitmap, android-studio

In creating a game with AndEngine with Android Studio, I put my assets folder at the project's root level. I also created a folder named gfx under it and put my splash.png there.

When I call the splash screen:

```
 public void loadSplashScreen()
{
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    splashTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 390, 534, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    splash_region = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(splashTextureAtlas, activity, "splash.png", 0, 0);
    splashTextureAtlas.load();
}
```

This is the error's that's produced

Am I putting something in the wrong place? Where should assets be?

```
     E/AndEngine﹕ Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: gfx/splash.png
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: gfx/splash.png
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:52)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:43)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:86)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:82)
            at com.waylonhuang.game.ResourcesManager.loadSplashScreen(ResourcesManager.java:68)
            at com.waylonhuang.game.SceneManager.createSplashScene(SceneManager.java:93)
            at com.waylonhuang.game.GameActivity.onCreateScene(GameActivity.java:62)
            at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$3.onCreateResourcesFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:171)
            at com.waylonhuang.game.GameActivity.onCreateResources(GameActivity.java:45)
            at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:183)
            at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:112)
            at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:80)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1501)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
01-17 16:48:21.329  30718-30749/com.waylonhuang.game E/AndEngine﹕ Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: gfx/splash.png
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: gfx/splash.png
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.onLoadBitmap(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:101)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.onLoadBitmap(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:85)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTextureAtlas.java:154)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:145)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:268)
            at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:633)
            at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
01-17 16:48:21.348  30718-30749/com.waylonhuang.game W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41717d40)
01-17 16:48:21.349  30718-30749/com.waylonhuang.game E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 6799
    Process: com.waylonhuang.game, PID: 30718
    org.andengine.util.exception.NullBitmapException: Caused by: class org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource --> AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource(gfx/splash.png) returned a null Bitmap.
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTextureAtlas.java:156)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:145)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:268)
            at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:633)
            at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
01-17 16:48:23.282  30718-30749/com.waylonhuang.game I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 30718 SIG: 9
01-17 16:59:01.645    2098-2098/com.waylonhuang.game D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-17 16:59:02.020    2098-2098/com.waylonhuang.game I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
    Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
01-17 16:59:02.052    2098-2098/com.waylonhuang.game D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-17 16:59:02.087    2098-2119/com.waylonhuang.game E/AndEngine﹕ Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: gfx/splash.png
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: gfx/splash.png
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:52)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:43)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:86)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:82)
            at com.waylonhuang.game.ResourcesManager.loadSplashScreen(ResourcesManager.java:68)
            at com.waylonhuang.game.SceneManager.createSplashScene(SceneManager.java:93)
            at com.waylonhuang.game.GameActivity.onCreateScene(GameActivity.java:62)
            at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$3.onCreateResourcesFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:171)
            at com.waylonhuang.game.GameActivity.onCreateResources(GameActivity.java:45)
            at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:183)
            at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:112)
            at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:80)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1501)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
01-17 16:59:02.106    2098-2119/com.waylonhuang.game E/AndEngine﹕ Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: gfx/splash.png
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: gfx/splash.png
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.onLoadBitmap(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:101)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.onLoadBitmap(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:85)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTextureAtlas.java:154)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:145)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:268)
            at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:633)
            at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
01-17 16:59:02.110    2098-2119/com.waylonhuang.game W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41717d40)
01-17 16:59:02.111    2098-2119/com.waylonhuang.game E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 7084
    Process: com.waylonhuang.game, PID: 2098
    org.andengine.util.exception.NullBitmapException: Caused by: class org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource --> AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource(gfx/splash.png) returned a null Bitmap.
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTextureAtlas.java:156)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:145)
            at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:268)
            at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:633)
            at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, you should create the "gfx" folder directly from eclipse, and then drag and drop the splash.png picture inside the folder, **making sure you Copy the file, not link it, when prompted.** Linking can generate accessability problems.
Here is a working project structure from one of my small projects in eclipse:

[image]

Here is what my caller method looks like:

```
public void loadSplashResources() {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/splash/");
    mSplashTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(mActivity.getTextureManager(), 480, 800, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    mSplashTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mSplashTextureAtlas, mActivity, "splash.png", 0, 0);
    mSplashTextureAtlas.load();
    mFont1 = FontFactory.create(mActivity.getFontManager(), mActivity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL), 10, Color.GRAY);
    mFont1.load();
}
```

also it is wise to have an unloader method for resource optimization purposes:

```
public void unloadSplashResources() {
    mSplashTextureAtlas.unload();
    mSplashTextureRegion = null;
    mFont1.unload();
    mFont1 = null;
}
```

In my main activity, I then call the loading of the splash screen while loading resources:

```
@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {

    mResourceManager = ResourceManager.getInstance();
    mResourceManager.prepare(this);
    mResourceManager.loadSplashResources();
    mSceneManager = SceneManager.getInstance();

}
```

and once I create a new scene, I unload the splash:

```
@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2f, new ITimerCallback() {
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
            mResourceManager.loadGameResources();
            mSceneManager.setScene(SceneType.SCENE_MENU);
            mResourceManager.unloadSplashResources();
        }
    }));
```

Hopefully you can cross reference these samples to see if your splash is anywhere similarly configured, and find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You have to create "assets" folder in path app/src/main/ and put "gfx" folder with splash.png into it

Comment: This structure allowed my main activity to load, but it still says file not found.Before; it said file not found and crashed my main activity.

Comment: Make sure that your file located in gfx folder (not in any other inner folder) and the file format in code exactly the same (sounds obvious, but sometimes people like me :) don't really pay attention)

Comment: I believe the file is found now, but i am getting a null bitmap exception

Comment: It is hard to say something... could you please share your code around lines where error occurs?